# Mosaic to Raster - successful but the layer does not show in layers or documents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, mosaic

I have used the Mosaic to New Raster tool and it works however the raster tif does not show in the layers or my documents, why is this happening and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm thinking the location of the file should be shown in that results window somewhere. You might want to edit the question to indicate what you did in the process of looking for the file.

Comment: I looked at the data location and the file is not there. Before I had been getting errors saying the output raster dataset: empty but it doesn't say that when it is located in the geodatabase rather than a folder.

Comment: You are writing the output to a file geodatabase (E:/ArcGis work/MyArcGisWork.gdb) but then give the raster name a ".tif" extension. This is an invalid name, simply call it "DEMsmosaic" as you are creating a file geodatabase raster dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can find where it is by right clicking on the "Output Raster Dataset" line in your result panel. you'll be prompted to add it to display or copy location.

[image: see output]

EDIT : from your edit, it's your default Arcgis processing database.

If you have removed by mistake your layer and have the "Resulat are temporary by default" option in, it may be lost:

[image]

You can also try to Ctrl + click the minus sign to see all your layers more easily. It may be in your windows but in the middle of your other layers ?

Comment: I did that but it did not work.

Comment: did you have a look in your gdb with ArcCatalog ?

Comment: It isn't in there, I have put a image of my gdb there is only three files.

Comment: Do I need to tick the Results are temporary by default box?

Comment: Oh, no. It was just in case you did. When you remove a result that has not been saved with this box ticked, it disappears. It could've explained the thing. That's strange indeed ! Could you right click on the Mosaic to new raster result tool icon and "Copy as Python snippet" ? Then you paste it here or in your question :)

Comment: Other hint : Can you try doing it again but saving in another place and see what happens ?

Comment: I have done it in other folders but it kept saying output raster dataset: empty but in the geodatabase that error doesn't occur, the raster just doesn't appear. I have put the Python snippet in the question.

Comment: It's very strange. Some more tests : try on a limited set of data, check for some projection problems, try to use another tool (create  raster catalog in a geodatabase, then Raster Catalog to raster dataset, or workspace to Raster dataset

Comment: Is this an issue of the output data not being visible in ArcCatalog?  ArcCatalog will not refresh the directories automatically so if Python creates data someplace you will need to navigate to the directory and hit the F5 button to refresh the display.